# Not able to connect to Excel 2016- 64 bit as Microsoft.Office.Inerop.Excel is not visible to add in References

Tags: c#, excel

I am using MS office 365 64 bit on windows 10 64 bit.

When I am trying to connect to excel 2016 (64bit), I want to add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel . But it is not visible either in Assembly or Extensions or in COM . The only item visible in COM is Microsoft.Excel 16.0 object library. When I tried to add Microsoft.Excel 16.0 object library to references, it gives the message:

> A reference to 'Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library' Could not be
>   added.

In such a situation, how could I connect to excel from Visual Studio Community Edition 2017?

Comment: Have you tried downloading it through the Nuget package manager?

Comment: Have you used Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library version 1.9?If same version used then if you have od refrence please remove that and then try once again